# bash, insert a condition in a command with pipes

Tags: linux, bash, pipe, conditional-statements

I need to create a file with some fields of another very huge file but only if field 3 is empty.

Actually I'm doing this:

```
cut -f 1,3,4,6 allCountries.txt | sort -u > cities_nostate.txt
```

then, with another script, I go through all the lines of the *cities_nostate.txt* file and check all the fields but this takes hours.

Is it possible to put a condition in the command in order to fast filter and remove all the useless lines (those with field 3 not empty) ?

---

After having accepted the answer, this is how I solved it:

```
awk -F'\t' '$3 == "" && $1 != "" && $4 != "" && $6 != "" {print $1, "\t", $4, "\t", $6}' allCountries.txt | sort -u >
```

Field 3 must be empty but all the others not.
I need a tab separator between the printed fields as there might be spaces inside each field.

Comment: `cut | awk 'some condition to filter out empty record 3' | sort`, basically

Comment: Is each field separated by exactly one space?

Comment: ok tnx, I'll give it a try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your fields are separated by tab characters and you only want to print the lines for which field 3 is empty, you can use this:

```
awk -F'\t' '$3 == ""{print $1,$3,$4,$6}' allCountries.txt
```

In awk, the default input field separator is any number of space characters (`[[:space:]]+`), so you cannot detect an empty field without changing it to something else.

To print the output columns separated by tabs, you can set the Output Field Separator variable `OFS`. This can be done in the `BEGIN` block before the file is processed:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}$3 == ""{print $1,$3,$4,$6}' allCountries.txt
```

I've assigned the input Field Separator to a tab character at the same time.

Comment: Ah ok, that's why it was not working with awk, I thought that the default delimiter was tab as the cut command. Thanks a lot, it wrote 30 mb in a few seconds ;)

Comment: I accepted the answer but it's a bit wrong as field 3 should be empty. Anyway I understood it and made my own thanks to your answer. I'll write my command in the question.

Comment: ok thanks again (to all), I've learned something today that will save me hours of work (well, of waiting at least) in the future ;)

Comment: @marco I've edited again to show a simpler way of getting tab characters between the fields in the output.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `cut` you can use awk:

```
awk '$3 == "" {print $1,$3,$4,$6}' allCountries.txt | sort -u > cities_nostate.txt
```

`$3 == ""` will print fields only when field 3 is empty.

Comment: If "field 3" is empty, won't that just mean that `$3` takes the value of the fourth field?

Comment: @Tom yep, in fact it works only if field 3 is not empty and this is the opposite of what I need. But thanks for the nice hint (@anubhava), didn't know about this awk feature.

Comment: Ah sorry, I had to step out for some work. Yes both of you are right. Also OP didn't have tab separator in question.

Comment: @anubhava that's because the default field separator in `cut` is a tab character